# Number of 0-simplices after second barycentric subdivision of a standard simplex

Tags: combinatorics, simplex, barycentric-coordinates

What is the number of 0-simplices of a standard $n$-simplex after its **second** barycentric subdivision? 
 By the way of counting, this number is 1, 5 and 25 for 0-, 1- and 2-simplices, respectively.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $m$-face. Let's take $n = 1$. The first barycentric subdivision of a $1$-simplex has $3$ $0$-simplices, $2$ $1$-simplices (which are its $2$ facets) and so $5$ simplices in total. As $2^{1+1} - 1 = 3$, it is unclear what you trying to count.

Comment: By the way, the close vote isn't from me, but you must clarify the question if it is to survive.

Comment: As best I can tell, your examples are counting $0$-cells. The numbers of $0$-simplices of the second barycentic subdivision of a $0$-simpiex, of a $1$-simplex, and of a $2$-simplex are 1, 5, and 25 respectively. So, I am guessing that you meant to ask "What is the number of $0$-simplices of the second barycentric subdivision of an $n$-simplex?". Is my guess correct?

Comment: Thank you, that's I guess the best description.